# Want to change the color of a HTML element from red to green then red again

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the color of a label from red to green, and then red again after 2 seconds using `setTimeout()`. It should be stopped after changing into red from green. This should happen 3 times in a loop. How do I do this?

```
 <script>
 setTimeout(a(),2000);

function a()
{
 var i;
 for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
  {
   if(i%2==0)
    {
     document.getElementById("s1").style.color="red";
     }
    else
      {
     document.getElementById("s1").style.color="green";
      }
     }
    }
  </script>
  <body onload="a()">
  <label id="s1">WELCOME</label>
    </body>
```

Comment: Why the modulus? if( i%2==0), seems senseless given your context. Also you did not ask a question you made a statement. What problem do you  currently face?

Answer (score 2):

1. The for-loop just execute immediately, you can only see its last change, which should be green. You need to pull the `i` out of the function, to keep the state, then use `setTimeout` to call self to change the color.
2. `setTimeout(a(),2000);` will immediately execute `function a`, you need to use `setTimeout(a,2000);` instead.
3. setTimeout(a(),2000); at the head of the script can be removed, just call `a` at your body.onload, and the `a` it self will take care of rest of the things.

```html
<script>
  var i = 0;
  function a() {
    var color = (i % 2 === 0) ? 'red' : 'green';
     document.getElementById("s1").style.color = color;
    ++i;
    if (i <= 2) {
      setTimeout(a, 2000);
    }
  }
</script>

<body onload="a();">
  <label id="s1">WELCOME</label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like following

```
<script>
 setTimeout(b, 2000);

 function a() {
    document.getElementById("s1").style.color="red";
 }

 function b() {
    document.getElementById("s1").style.color="green";
    setTimeout(a, 2000);
 }
</script>

<body onload="a()">
  <label id="s1">WELCOME</label>
</body>
```

Comment: You can do just `setTimeout(a, 2000)`. `a` already is a function, there is no need to wrap it into another, same with `b`.

Comment: @MarceloCamargo - I agree with you, however, I like to wrap up like above. However, I have accepted your edit :)

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest using CSS animations instead of JavaScript to do this. In JavaScript keeping track of state is tricky—it's much easier to specify this in CSS. Bonus: your code will be a lot less cluttered.

This particular example will loop indefinitely, but you can easily look up documentation on how to use CSS animations.

```html
<style>
@keyframes redgreen {
  0%, 50%, 100% { color: red; }
  25%, 75% { color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes redgreen {
  0%, 50%, 100% { color: red; }
  25%, 75% { color: green; }
}
</style>

<label style="animation: 2s redgreen;-webkit-animation: 2s redgreen infinite;">Hey!</label>
```